# Netlogo multiple patch layer

Tags: netlogo

Can I create multiple patch layers in Netlogo, instead of using several patch variables in one layer?

I'm trying to integrate different maps (geology, traffic, etc.) into the Netlogo environment. So far, I've defined multiple patch variables using patches-own command. But the maps I have are not always stackable. So if I can have separate patch layers for different maps, it would be clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make more patch layers. The structure of the NetLogo patch world is fixed.

But you might consider representing the information using turtles instead. You can sprout them, one per patch, or you could define several breeds of turtle, and have each patch sprout one of each breed. The order in which the breeds are defined will determine the layers' stacking order, and you can hide or show whole layers using `hide-turtle` and `show-turtle`. If you want the turtles to look just like patches, do `set shape "square"` (adjusting the size of the "square" shapes in the turtle shapes editor if necessary).